# Fun with google analytics api; token error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, api, google-analytics

**UPDATE: I've added an answer to my question that solves my problem (although its not 100% tested) - still have to wait for the token refresh to occur. Still would love to hear others input.**

I'm experiencing a problem when working with googles analytics api for php.

I am initiating the api (the full script of which can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/2uYKBfCC); it is an older version) via a function called in my constructor where I setup and define all the variables the api needs and then check to make sure I have a valid token. I have an AJAX controller that calls 4 functions in my class asynchronously to show relevant analytics statistics to user via googles chart api. If there is an error then an error is displayed in that specific chart block. If we have an error there is 100% chance of the error will be coming from whether or not we are establishing a proper token as the statements that get the data from ga are prepared.

Since all 4 charts/displays correspond to different functions in the class we are running 4 queries to google analytics. However, sometimes one of the charts gets a 'Token error' response, sometimes more than one of the charts does... Sometimes it doesn't happen at all. I figured that this might have been due to the fact that in the AJAX call I initiated my class as `new` rather than getting an instance of the class, and therefore only 1 call e.g. one construct of the class to get our token. So I implemented a singleton-type design calling the class once via `$ga = Google_Analytics_Stats::getInstance($gaInfo);` but the issue persists.

Does anyone know what might be causing this intermittent token error?

For clarity

`Google_Analytics_Stats` initializes `GoogleAnalyticsAPI` in `initAnalytics($gaInfo)` where `$gaInfo` is the relevant account and email details. AJAX.php switches between functions based on type that are in `Google_Analytics_Stats` which is only initialized once using `$ga = Google_Analytics_Stats::getInstance($gaInfo);`

AJAX call:

```
<?php
require ('../framework.php');
$login->protect(false);
if (!isAjax()) {
    redirect('index.php');
}
// dont forget these functions use date so user timezone effects it!!!
error_reporting(0);
$ga = Google_Analytics_Stats::getInstance($gaInfo);

switch (isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : '') {
    case 'map':
        if (isset($_GET['ga_length'])) {
            echo $ga->getVisitsByCountries($_GET['ga_length']);
        }
        else {
            $error = array(
                "status" => "error",
                "error"  => 'No length defined'
            );
            echo json_encode($error);
        }

        break;
    case 'bounceRate':
        echo $ga->displayBounceRate();
        break;
    case 'visitsToday':
        echo $ga->getVisitsToday();
        break;
    case 'momVisits':
        echo $ga->displayMonthOverMonthVisits();
        break;
    case 'newVsReturn':
        if (isset($_GET['ga_length'])) {
            echo $ga->getNewVsReturn($_GET['ga_length']);
        }
        else {
            $error = array(
                "status" => "error",
                "error"  => 'No length defined'
            );
            echo json_encode($error);
        }
        break;
    case 'visitsByDate':
        if (isset($_GET['ga_length'])) {
            echo $ga->getVisitsByDate($_GET['ga_length']);
        }
        else {
            $error = array(
                "status" => "error",
                "error"  => 'No length defined'
            );
            echo json_encode($error);
        }
        break;
}
?>
```

Main code (only 1st necessary parts for conceptualizing):

```
class Google_Analytics_Stats {

    private $ga;
    // array for default $len
    private $bounce_rate_current = '';
    private $monthly_visitors_current = '';
    // rounding precision
    private $precision = 1;
    private $len;
    public static $instance;

    function __construct($gaInfo)
    {
        $this->initAnalytics($gaInfo);
        $this->len = array(
            'start-date' => date(DATE_FORMAT, strtotime('-1 month')),
            'end-date'   => date(DATE_FORMAT)
        );
    }
    public static function getInstance($gaInfo)
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new Google_Analytics_Stats($gaInfo);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
    private function initAnalytics($gaInfo)
    {
        try {
            $ga = new GoogleAnalyticsAPI('service');
            $accountId = $gaInfo['account_id'];
            $ga->auth->setClientId($gaInfo['client_id']);
            $ga->auth->setEmail($gaInfo['email']);
            $ga->auth->setPrivateKey($gaInfo['key_src']);
            $auth = $ga->auth->getAccessToken();
            // try and get access token
            if ($auth['http_code'] == 200) {
                $accessToken = $auth['access_token'];
                $tokenExpires = $auth['expires_in'];
                $tokenCreated = time();
            }
            else {
                throw new Exception('Token error');
            }
            // set token and account id
            $ga->setAccessToken($accessToken);
            $ga->setAccountId($accountId);
            // set defaults
            /*
              if (isset($this->len)) {
              $ga->setDefaultQueryParams($this->len);
              }
             */
            $this->ga = $ga;
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $error = array(
                "status" => "error",
                "error"  => $e->getMessage()
            );
            //output result
            echo json_encode($error);
        }
    }

    public function getBounceRate($params = '')
    {
        $defaults = array('metrics' => 'ga:bounceRate');
        $_params = array_merge($defaults, $params);
        $result = $this->ga->_query($_params);
        return $result['rows'][0][0];
    }

    public function getBounceRateCurrent()
    {
        $params = array(
            'start-date' => date(DATE_FORMAT, strtotime('-1 month')),
            'end-date'   => date(DATE_FORMAT) //now
        );
        $result = $this->getBounceRate($params);
        return round($result, $this->precision);
    }

    public function bounceRateTextual($percentage)
    {
        if ($this->inRange($percentage, 0, 25.9)) {
            return array('display' => 'success', 'text' => 'Extremel low');
        }
        elseif ($this->inRange($percentage, 26, 40.9)) {
            return array('display' => 'success', 'text' => 'Below average');
        }
        elseif ($this->inRange($percentage, 41, 55.9)) {
            return array('display' => 'warning', 'text' => 'Average');
        }
        elseif ($this->inRange($percentage, 56, 70.9)) {
            return array('display' => 'danger', 'text' => 'Higher than average');
        }
        else {
            return array('display' => 'danger', 'text' => 'Extremely high');
        }
    }

    public function displayBounceRate()
    {
        // has to be called first or current will be empty
        $current = $this->getBounceRateCurrent();
        $out = '<h6 class="text-uppercase">Bounce Rate this month</h6>';
        $out .= '<h1>' . $current . '%</h1>';
        $changeWrapper = "<span class='text-muted mr-0-5'>Rating:</span><span class='label label-%s label-small'>%s</span>";
        $textual = $this->bounceRateTextual($current);
        $out .= sprintf($changeWrapper, $textual['display'], $textual['text']);
        return $out;
    }
```

Comment: Singleton or not, each Ajax call is a brand new request to your back end and will therefore create new instances of your classes. Different Ajax calls can't share the same instance. You could make one ajax call that returns all the charts you need in one go and just display them separately in the front end?

Comment: Hey magnus thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I can't do that as I'm rendering directly into Google charts, not to mention it wouldn't be manageable. I guess what that leaves is finding another solution,  perhaps based around why subsequent token requests are (sometimes) being denied

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I figured that perhaps the issue was I was getting a new token so often when the old one was already valid that I was flooding googles system and they were revoking access every now and again to reduce server load. So what I've done is store the token in a session variable along with when the token was created and when it will expire and if it is expired I get a new one. Thus far it has been working with no token errors :fingers-crossed: ... Following other articles I found online I've also implemented a try again feature that will try and get the token again should `getToken` come back false. At which point, if it still fails, we'll throw the token error.

As a side benefit, it is loading the front-end page alot faster haha

```
private function initAnalytics($gaInfo)
    {
        try {
            $ga = new GoogleAnalyticsAPI('service');
            $accountId = $gaInfo['account_id'];
            $ga->auth->setClientId($gaInfo['client_id']);
            $ga->auth->setEmail($gaInfo['email']);
            $ga->auth->setPrivateKey($gaInfo['key_src']);
            // set ga to ga so getToken can use the vars we set above
            $this->ga = $ga;
            // attempt to get token; 1st attempt
            if($this->getToken() === false) {
                // 2nd attempt
                if($this->getToken() === false) {
                    throw new Exception ('Token Error. Refresh page.');
                }
            }
            // unset ga as we are going to set it again with the access token initialized 
            unset($this->ga);
            $ga->setAccessToken($_SESSION['ga_access_token']);
            $ga->setAccountId($accountId);  
            // set defaults
            /*
              if (isset($this->len)) {
              $ga->setDefaultQueryParams($this->len);
              }
             */
            $this->ga = $ga;

        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $error = array(
                "status" => "error",
                "error"  => $e->getMessage()
            );
            //output result
            echo json_encode($error);
        }
    }

    public function getToken() 
    {
        // check to see if we have a token
        if (isset($_SESSION['ga_token_created']) && isset($_SESSION['ga_token_expires']) && isset($_SESSION['ga_access_token'])) { 
            // check to see if the token is still valid, if not, refresh it
            if ((time() - $_SESSION['ga_token_created']) >= $_SESSION['ga_token_expires']) {
                $auth = $this->ga->auth->refreshAccessToken($refreshToken);
                if ($auth['http_code'] == 200) {
                    // now we can unset the old session vars ...
                    unset($_SESSION['ga_access_token']);
                    unset($_SESSION['ga_token_created']);
                    unset($_SESSION['ga_token_expires']);
                    // ... and add the new ones
                    $_SESSION['ga_access_token'] = $auth['access_token'];
                    $_SESSION['ga_token_expires'] = $auth['expires_in'];
                    $_SESSION['ga_token_created'] = time();
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        // nothing was set so we go the usual route
        } else {
            $auth = $this->ga->auth->getAccessToken();
            // try and get access token
            if ($auth['http_code'] == 200) {
                $_SESSION['ga_access_token'] = $auth['access_token'];
                $_SESSION['ga_token_expires'] = $auth['expires_in'];
                $_SESSION['ga_token_created'] = time();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```